# Does an index create a new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, rdbms

I’m having trouble understanding exactly what happens when I create an index. So if I create an index on (Col1, Col2). Will there be a new table created containing only Col1 and Col2 which my query will run on?

Or do I specify that I’m using an index in my query and then for that query and that query only my table is now reduced to (Col1, Col2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an index on a table, internally it doesn't create any new table but just index. This index is physically separate and has data organized like a tree (usually B+ tree) which helps in faster lookups and speeds up the queries that have where clause having the column name on which index are created. If you don't create indexes on table then the queries on that table may have to do full table scan in order to find records. Indexes can be unique or non unique.

Comment: This was very clear and lined up with the visual representation I found in the link posted below. Thank You

Comment: Pleased to know it helped you.